# How Do I Use Loops to Find Sums in Array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

So I need to use a loop to fill an array with the total amount. The total amount will be the amount spent plus a gift card that is a percentage. So

```
total = amountSpent + amountSpent*(1+giftCard)
```

I am having trouble getting the total. The spent and gift card amounts are all randomly generated using math.random. The spent and gift card amounts are each found in separate arrays, with the spent amount being anywhere between 0 to 500, and gift card amount being anywhere from 0 to 50.

```
 var spent = new Array(5);
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
      randS = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
      spent[i] = randS;
 }

 var gifts = new Array(5);
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
      randG= Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
      gifts[i] = randG;
 }
```

These are how I fill the arrays using a for loop. I am now supposed to create a new array and use a loop to calculate the total. I defined 2 variables for spent and gift card amount, but I am unsure if they are calling the correct numbers.

```
 var totals = new Array(5);
 var tSpent = spent;
 var tGifts = gifts;
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
      totals[i] = tSpent + (1 + (tGifts / 100)) * tSpent;
      totals[i] = totals[i].toFixed(2);
 }
```

I know this array is the problem since the other two arrays are displaying the numbers fine. I also have to convert the gift card amount to a decimal and make sure the total is to 2 decimal places.

Comment: You forgot to index your `tSpent` and `tGifts` right?  Should the one line say: `totals[i] tSpent[i] + ( 1 + (tGifts[i] / 100)) * tSpent[i];` ??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am able to understand your question, I feel you are doing it correct, just a small correction needs to be done in your code.

```
 var totals = new Array(5);
 var tSpent = spent;
 var tGifts = gifts;
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
      totals[i] = tSpent[i] + (1 + (tGifts[i] / 100)) * tSpent[i];
      totals[i] = totals[i].toFixed(2);
 }
```

Also, your arrays `tSpend` and `tGifts` are calling correct numbers, although they seem redundant, unless you have something planned for them later in code. If not, they are just directly referencing your actual variable spend and gifts.

Answer (score 0):

you can write the whole code in one loop like this:

```
var spent=[],gifts=[],totals=[];
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    spent[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    gifts[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    totals[i] = spent[i] + (1 + gifts[i]/10)*spent[i]
    totals[i] = totals[i].toFixed(2);
}
```